# Replacing CompareTo with LINQ for array elements

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop

I am working on a project which uses posts to represent a fence. Each fence has exactly two posts that implement IComparable and are ordered in each fence. In order to override my CompareTo on Fence, I need to compare post 0 between this and the other fence; if that result returns 0, then I need to compare post 1 between this and the other fence. I wrote a simple for loop to perform this logic, which I've included below. However, Resharper is giving me a warning that I should replace the for loop with LINQ. Is there an easy way to replace the for loop with LINQ?

```
public int CompareTo(Fence other)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Posts.Length; i++)
    {
        int c = Posts[i].CompareTo(other.Posts[i]);
        if (c != 0)
            return c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If resharper suggests it, why don't you hit Alt+Enter and look what happens?

Comment: It's not a warning, it's just a suggestion.

Comment: Maybe it's just a hint? In certain cases Resharper can transform non-LINQ code blocks to LINQ and vice versa.

Comment: Also shouldn't you be doing a length check in case `other` has fewer posts?

Comment: @juharr The constructor for Fence enforces there are exactly two posts.

Comment: @dwelknarr If there are only two posts why even bother with an array, just have `Post1` and `Post2` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ReSharper suggests it you may easily hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and see what happens. I guess something like:

```
public int CompareTo(Fence other)
{
    return Posts.Select((p, i) => p.CompareTo(other.Posts[i]))
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c != 0);
}
```

This *projects* each `Post` to it's comparison result to the respective `Post` of the `other` `Fence` (`p` is the `Post` loop variable, `i` is the index). `FirstOrDefault` looks for the first non-zero comparsion result or returns `0` if *all* results are `0`.

So this does exactly what your loop does (note that LINQ uses *deferred execution*, so when the first non-zero comparison occures, no further `Post`s are compared).

---

Note that this code is error-prone, as juharr commented: you should first null-check `other` and check if the two `Post` arrays have the same length.
(I guess that `Posts` is not null and the arrays don't contain `null` elements should be ensured by your classes' implementations).

Comment: I removed the null check in my post to simplify it on SO. The Posts property in Fence is immutable, and the constructor enforces that there are exactly two, non-null, non-equal Post objects.

Answer (score 1):

Since a Fence has exactly two Posts, then this can be reduced to :

```
public int CompareTo(Fence other)
{
    int c = Post[0].CompareTo(other.Post[0]);
    if (c == 0)
         c = Post[1].CompareTo(other.Post[1]);
    return c;
}
```

Note that you can (and probably should) replace the `Post` array with `Post0` and `Post1'.

Note, that this could give you a completely different ordering than:

```
    int c = Post[1].CompareTo(other.Post[1]);
    if (c == 0)
         c = Post[0].CompareTo(other.Post[0]);
```

which, presumably, is just as valid.  (i.e, if this Post[0] is less than the other's, but it's Post[1] is greater, is the Fence greater or less than the other?)